# Resharper 7.1 messing up Visual Studio 2012 preview feature

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.1

I've installed Resharper 7.1, and I'm getting some strange behaviour
When navigating through code using F12 (go to definition), VS 2012 was usually displaying the preview tab on the upper right hand side, to avoid lots of files being open and stacking up
However, I've noticed that now it behaves erratically
I've tried with resharper on and off, this is what happens

Resharper ON : when pressing F12 into a base class name (or any class definition), instead of previewing the file, VS just opens the file (same that happened in VS 2010). 
Resharper OFF : when pressing F12 into a base class name (or any class definition), VS opens the preview tab, file doesn't stay open

So, I assume that Resharper is doing something with the shortcuts or some strange option that's messing the preview feature
More strange is that SOMETIMES it does work with resharper, but I couldn't find a distinctive pattern of when it's working and when it's not...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was a FEATURE! (can't believe it...)

http://sticklebackplastic.com/post/2013/02/01/New-ReSharper-plugin-bringing-the-preview-tab-back.aspx